# SQL Query output - decimal placment, too many integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query functioning properly, I'm combining two tables, removing duplicates and keeping data with the most recent effective date.

The tables look like this:

```
1.TAX_TABLE---------    
tax_id  description

        1   AZ State
        2   AZ-Maricopa Co
        4   AZ-Maricopa/Mesa



2.Tax_RATE_TABLE-------
tax_id  effective_date  tax_percent

1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 5.6
2   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 0.7
4   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 1.75
4   2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 2
```

My current query looks like this:

```
use lhsitedb
select t.tax_id, t.description, tr.effective_date, tr.tax_percent
from dbo.tax t
inner join dbo.tax_rate tr on tr.tax_id = t.tax_id
where tr.effective_date = (
    select max(tr1.effective_date)
    from dbo.tax_rate tr1
    where tr1.tax_id = tr.tax_id
```

My output comes out with this, where I'm getting fractional digits within the tax_tax percentage column. I've been trying to make restrictions on that column to only display decimal numbers that can scale up to hundredths.

Note: This query works just fine when executed in SSMS, however, I'm utilizing `sqlcmd` and exported the file into a `.txt` file which is where these unexpected results are being produced.

```
tax_id                description                     effective_date          tax_percent             
--------------------- ------------------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------
                    4 AZ-Maricopa/Mesa                2019-03-01 00:00:00.000                        2
                    2 AZ-Maricopa Co                  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000      0.69999999999999996
                    1 AZ State                        2015-01-01 00:00:00.000       5.5999999999999996

(17 rows affected)
```

When that column, should look more along these lines:

```
         tax_percent  
   ----------------------------
                   2 
                   1.75
```

Comment: What's the data type for `tax_percent`?

Comment: It is set to 'float'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated my answer to use CONVERT function ...

I would try to use the `CONVERT` function.. give it a shot! The 2 will specify the hundredths. `CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),tr.tax_percent) as 'tax_percent'`

```
use lhsitedb
select t.tax_id, t.description, tr.effective_date, 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),tr.tax_percent) AS 
'tax_percent' 
from dbo.tax t
inner join dbo.tax_rate tr on tr.tax_id = t.tax_id
where tr.effective_date = (
    select max(tr1.effective_date)
    from dbo.tax_rate tr1
    where tr1.tax_id = tr.tax_id
```

Comment: No luck here, surprisingly still receiving the same output.

Comment: So, this query works just fine when executed Server Management Studio, however, I'm utilizing sqlcmd and exported the file into a .txt file. For whatever reason, I'm still seeing the excess decimal points.

Comment: ahh... I got you. I updated my answer to use a CONVERT function ... let me know if that works

Comment: Also if that doesn't work @JonnyDavy you could try putting this data into a temp table then exporting it.

Comment: mind marking it as an answer mate? I'm new to this game

Answer (score 1):

First, you can simplify your query using `apply`.

Second, you would appear to be storing the values as `float`s rather than `decimal`/`numeric`.  Well, you can fix this on output:

```
select t.tax_id, t.description, tr.effective_date,
       round(tr.tax_percent, 2)
from dbo.tax t cross apply
     (select top (1) tr.*
      from dbo.tax_rate tr 
      where tr.tax_id = t.tax_id
      order by tr.effective_date desc
     ) tr
```

Comment: It looks right but for what ever reason : Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "tr1.effective_date" could not be bound.

Comment: @JonnyDavy . . . That was a typo.

Comment: So, this query works just fine when executed Server Management Studio, however, I'm utilizing sqlcmd and exported the file into a .txt file. For whatever reason, I'm still seeing the excess decimal points.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: ["Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) Both `float` and `real` are subject to some display oddities.

I'd try an explicit `CAST`. Something like:

```
use lhsitedb
select 
  t.tax_id, 
  t.description, 
  tr.effective_date, 
  CAST(tr.tax_percent AS decimal(18,2)) AS tax_percent --<-- The only change is here.
from dbo.tax t
inner join dbo.tax_rate tr on tr.tax_id = t.tax_id
where tr.effective_date = (
    select max(tr1.effective_date)
    from dbo.tax_rate tr1
    where tr1.tax_id = tr.tax_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eric, this worked as well. Same results as @BadBoyBI

Answer (score 0):

You could use str()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

```
str(your_value, 3, 2);  


select t.tax_id, t.description, tr.effective_date, str(tr.tax_percent,3,2)
```